# How do I request a new certificate from a Windows 2016 Issuing CA which has an expired certificate?

Tags: windows-server-2016, ad-certificate-services

We have an offline RootCA which still has a valid certificate.   Our subordinate issuing CA unfortunately expired before we renewed.  How does one recover from this scenario? Windows Server 2016 environment.

Comment: just go through renewal process as normally.

Comment: So this is Windows 2016 Core.  When using remote mmc I'm not seeing an option for this. I'm presuming I'm going to need to do this via command line on the console somehow?

Comment: `certutil -renewcert` and then `cerutil -installcert`

Comment: CertUtil: -renewCert command FAILED: 0x8007139f (WIN32: 5023 ERROR_INVALID_STATE)
CertUtil: The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.  I'm presuming this is because it's expired?

Comment: I should add that the RootCA is an offline .

Comment: Add `f` switch: `certutil -f -renewcert`. This command will generate a request  which is placed in root directory of system drive. Submit the request to root CA, download the certificate and run `certutil -installcert`.

Answer (score 2):

As Crypt32 stated, the solution to this was simply to use certutil -f -renewcert but with reusekeys option.  Then submit the request on the Offline CA, approve, export the cert to a file to be installed on the issuing CA.